# Is there an uncountable set of the digit 8 in the plane?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to draw in the plane an uncountable set of the digit 8 such that the lines of two different digits won't cut?
I think it's wrong, I guess I need to find rational coordinates in every digit, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: How are you defining the digit $8$?

Comment: Standard trick:  Given an "$8$" you can pick a pair of rational points, one in each of the two circles.  There are only countably many such pairs.

Comment: Every "8" contains a "Y" and it is already impossible to place uncountably many "Y"'s in the plane - though the Y-problem is harder to prove than the 8-problem

Comment: @ParclyTaxel for the intended proof to work: The connected boundary of a  non-connected bounded open set :)